# How do I search for a value in an integer table using LIKE and <cfqueryparam>?

Tags: sql, t-sql, coldfusion

I have a query similar to this:

SELECT itemID
FROM itemTable
WHERE itemID LIKE '%123%'

itemTable is of type INT.  This query works just fine by itself, as it would select '12345' and '0912398' and so on...

The problem occurs when I try to use

Let's say var searchValue = 123

If I try: `<cfqueryparam cfsqltype='cf_sql_integer' value="'%#searchValue#%'" >`

I get *Invalid data '123' for CFSQLTYPE CF_SQL_INTEGER.*

If I try: `<cfqueryparam cfsqltype='cf_sql_varchar' value="'%#searchValue#%'" >`

I get *java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String*

I've tried using CAST in my SQL, and also using toString(searchValue) in various places, but I always end up with one of the error messages above.  Is there any way to search and integer table using CFQUERYPARAM?

EDIT: Below is the actual code I am trying to use...

CFSCRIPT Code:

```
var searchValue=123;
searchFilterQuery(qry=qItemResults, field="itemID", value=searchValue,cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar");
```

CFC Function:

```
<!--- FILTER A QUERY WITH SEARCH TERM --->
<cffunction name="searchFilterQuery" access="public" returntype="query" hint="Filters a query by the given value" output="false">
    <!--- ************************************************************* --->
    <cfargument name="qry"          type="query"    required="true" hint="Query to filter">
    <cfargument name="field"        type="string"   required="true" hint="Field to filter on">
    <cfargument name="value"        type="string"   required="true" hint="Value to filter on">
    <cfargument name="cfsqltype"    type="string"   required="false" default="cf_sql_varchar" hint="The cf sql type of the value.">
    <!--- ************************************************************* --->
    <cfset var qryNew = QueryNew("")>
    <cfquery name="qryNew" dbtype="query">
        SELECT *
            FROM arguments.qry
            WHERE #trim(arguments.field)# LIKE <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="#trim(arguments.cfsqltype)#" value="#trim(arguments.value)#">
    </cfquery>
    <cfreturn qryNew>
</cffunction>
```

Comment: RE: `I get *Invalid data '123' for CFSQLTYPE CF_SQL_INTEGER.*` .. That is because CF expects your `value` to be a valid `integer` like `123` or `212`. But what you are actually passing in is the literal string: `'%123%'`. Obviously not an integer. Hence the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do this, I reckon:

- remove the quotes as people have said
- use a VARCHAR param, not an INTEGER, as the % symbols make the value you're passing not an INTEGER
- CAST the integer column as a VARCHAR on the DB side of things.  The DB could possibly do this automatically for you, but I reckon it's better to be explicit about these things.

  SELECT itemID
  FROM itemTable
  WHERE CAST(itemId AS VARCHAR) LIKE <cfqueryparam cfsqltype='cf_sql_varchar' value="%#searchValue#%">

Comment: Yup. CAST(#trim(arguments.field)# as varchar) works just peachy.  It thought I had tried CAST before, but I must've gotten the syntax wrong, or left the quotes or something.  Thanks Adam, and everyone else!

Answer (score 0):

If you take your apostrophes off the one using varchar, that will work.

Comment: Should nto be using the single quotes in either one. The DBMS will take care of adding quotes if they are needed. You never need to add quotes to your values when using cfqueryparam

Comment: You are right, I was about to pad my answer out a bit. Basically you are passing the apostrophes through as part of your value at the moment.

Comment: Taking out the apostrophes from the varchar statement results in the same error: 
"java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String"

Removing the apostrophes from the statement using cf_sql_integer gets:
"Encountered "itemID LIKE 123. Incorrect conditional expression, Expected one of [like|null|between|in|comparison] condition, "

Comment: @eterps - Is this a QoQ? If so you probably need an explicit `cast`. Can you post your +exact+ query and CF version?

Comment: Use it with cf_sql_varchar and see what happens

Comment: @eterps - It works fine for me with `cf_sql_varchar` (implicit casting). But it would be good to see your actual sql to understand why it is not working for you. Seems like something is different ..

Comment: @eterps - You need to `cast` the column as a `varchar`. A QoQ will not do it for you automatically.